# The API - gateway project gets Eureka configuration information from the config server, how can it be registered with Eureka

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

In the file bootstrap.yml, the configuration is registered to Eureka information, as follows:

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://user:password123@localhost:8761/eureka
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

The API - gateway project can be started normally

Configure Eureka information to git repose,
The API - gateway project gets Eureka configuration information from the config server.Start the project API - gateway, but I have an exception：
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server。
Application of the main class：

```
@SpringCloudApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

     new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
  }

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
    public ZuulProperties zuulProperties() {
        return new ZuulProperties();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

git repose configuration file:

```
 zuul.routes.app-user.path=/loadUser/**
zuul.routes.app-user.serviceId=microservice-provider-user-v2
zuul.prefix=/api

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://user:password123@localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=3
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```